# Netlogo: How to transfer lists belonging to neighbours to a matrix?

Tags: list, matrix, netlogo

A list called ownList2 consists of two parameters. Flockmates are all the neighbours in a given radius of the neighbour. I tried this code in version 6.0. But it doesn't work. 
Basically, I want to put a list of equal dimension into a matrix. Is there something wrong I am doing? Or someone could improve the code piece?

```
ask turtles[set ownList2 (list who sensed)] 
;sensed is sensor value of a turtle with respect to the patch. 
;ownList2 is like a message of two bytes, 
    ;first byte mentioning the identity of the itself 
    ;second byte mentioning the value of the sensor. 

ask turtles[
    foreach (list flockmates)
    [
       i -> set m45 matrix:to-column-list ( list [ownList2] of i )
    ]
   ]
```

Result: 
     For turtle-0 with neighbours 1, 2, 3:
     ownList2 ~ [1 200] 
                [2 400] 
                [3 900]
The m43 for turtle-0 should look like
[[1 200][2 400][3 900]]

Comment: Can you provide a little more detail? It may be easiest to simply provide a toy version of your model (see the Help section on [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)), or you could give some examples of what a turtle's `ownList2` might look like and what you're expecting `m45` to look like once your code is run/

Comment: Does this help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for adding that information. Here is a toy example that might do what you need:

```
extensions [ matrix ]

turtles-own [ ownlist2 sensed m45 ]

to setup
  ca

  ; Setup example turtles as per question
  foreach [ 100 200 400 900 ] [
    n ->
    crt 1 [
      while [ any? other turtles-here ] [
        move-to one-of neighbors4
      ]
      set sensed n
      set ownlist2 ( list who sensed )
    ]
  ]

  ; Get the turtles to create matrices from the ownlists of
  ; sorted other turtles
  ask turtles [
    set m45 matrix:from-column-list map [ i -> [ ownlist2] of i ] sort other turtles
  ]

  ; Example output:
  ask turtle 0 [
    print "Turtle 0's m45:"
    print matrix:pretty-print-text m45
  ]

  reset-ticks
end
```

Output example:

```
Turtle 0's m45:
[[   1    2    3 ]
 [ 200  400  900 ]]
```